# Real World Haskell, Chapter 5, exercises: how to fill all the requirements and what they exactly are?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to go through the [mentioned chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/writing-a-library-working-with-json-data.html). While reading and thinking about exercises i faced several difficulties.

- First of all, should not be the signatures of `fill` and `nest` functions to be `:: Int -> Doc -> String`? I assumed that book is correct - they should not.
- Next, whether in exercise 1 it is meant that only the out-of-margin lines should not be filled with spaces or entire text should not be processed if at least one such line appears?
- The next question is about exercise 2. I almost entirely don't understand what authors meant. There can be two interpretations of what they meant: either we should produce something like

  ```
  {"foo": 123,
   "bar": 456}
  ```

  meaning that indentation of the first lexeme after opening delimiter (brace or bracket) is remembered and the next lines are indented with that amount of indentation (and then the first `nest` argument makes no sense), or we should produce (with `amount of indentation = 4`)

  ```
  {
      "foo": {
          "baz": 123
      },
      "bar": 456
  }
  ```

  but it makes no sense if user forgets to insert line breaks after/before opening/closing delimiters. Or should we force this insertion? Is it possible? (I know it's possible to always insert line breaks, but is it possible to recognize whether user inserted them himself?).

Please also note that i have taken a requirement not to add more data constructors to `Doc` type.

Comment: Have a look at the online version of the book: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/writing-a-library-working-with-json-data.html -- there are a lot of comments about the exercises.

Comment: @user5402 That's the one i'm reading. But nonetheless there seems to be no answer there to my question. Only "i think", "i assume" and so on.

Comment: You could try emailing Brian himself. His github handle is 'bos' and that's also his reddit handle. In fact, if you post these questions to /r/haskell he might feel compelled to respond.

Comment: What could be more "real world" than fuzzy and self-contradictory requirements?

Comment: 1. Why should it be `String`? You would then be able to do only `fill` or `nest`, not both. Does that restriction make sense? 2. Most likely *document width* is the width of the longest line. 3. There can be as many interpretations as there are indentation styles. Of course you're supposed to add line breaks and only if they weren't there. 4. Most importantly, why is this a question? Are you doing these for school? If not, pick an interpretation which is not too trivial and go with it. The differences are mostly superficial.

Comment: This question is overly broad. Can you pose a bunch of separate questions for each issue?

Comment: @Carl Good point, but should not we be able to pinpoint requirements after talk with client?

Comment: @user5402 Tried on email, still no response. (after a month or so)

Answer (score 7):

## Exercise 1

Going through the book myself, I was stuck on how to interpret the requirements of the first exercise. After a bit of searching, I hit upon [this approach to the problem](https://barryallison.wordpress.com/2009/07/27/real-world-haskell-chapter-5-%E2%80%93-haskell/).

The idea is that every time you encounter a `Line`, you first pad out the `Doc` *before* the `Line`.

Barry Allison's posted solution seems to have lost some `<>` characters in HTML formatting, but if I put them back into the places I guess they're supposed to go, his code seems to work.

The drawback of that solution is that it doesn't pad the last line, so I've modified the implementation to do that:

```
fill :: Int -> Doc -> Doc
fill width x = hcat (init (scanLines 0 [x <> Line]))
  where
    scanLines _ []         = []
    scanLines col (d:ds) =
      case d of
        Empty        -> scanLines col ds
        Char c       -> Char c : scanLines (col + 1) ds
        Text s       -> Text s : scanLines (col + length s) ds
        Line         -> Text (padLine (width - col)) : Line : scanLines 0 ds
        a `Concat` b -> scanLines col (a:b:ds)
        _ `Union` b  -> scanLines col (b:ds)
    padLine w = replicate w ' '
```

In order to pad the last line, the `fill` function first appends a `Line` to the input, and then calls `scanLines`. The difference from Barry Allison's solution is that in this implementation, `scanLines` has the type `Int -> [Doc] -> [Doc]`. This means that `init` can be used to throw away the trailing `Line`, and `hcat` can finally turn the `[Doc]` into a `Doc`.

The drawback of this solution is that it throws away the flattened version of the any `Union`.

If you modify `padLine` to `replicate` the character `'#'` instead of `' '`, you can see this output:

```
*PrettyJSON> let value = renderJValue (JObject [("f", JNumber 1), ("q", JBool True)])

*PrettyJSON> putStrLn (pretty 20 (Prettify.fill 30 value))
{"f": 1.0,####################
"q": true#####################
}#############################
```

It's likely that there's a more idiomatic and elegant solution to this exercise, but I'm posting this based on what I've learned so far from reading the book.

---

## Exercise 2

When it came to the second exercise, I took some liberties with interpreting the requirements. As other people have pointed out, both here and elsewhere, the requirements aren't clear.

The following, then, is more of a sketch of solution:

```
nest :: Int -> Doc -> Doc
nest indentation x = indent 0 [x]
  where
    indent _ []             = Empty
    indent nestLevel (d:ds) =
      case d of
        Empty        -> indent nestLevel ds
        Char '{'     -> padLine nestLevel <> Char '{' <> indent (nestLevel + 1) (Line:ds)
        Char '}'     -> padLine (nestLevel - 1) <> Char '}' <> indent (nestLevel - 1) ds
        Char '['     -> padLine nestLevel <> Char '[' <> indent (nestLevel + 1) (Line:ds)
        Char ']'     -> padLine (nestLevel - 1) <> Char ']' <> indent (nestLevel - 1) ds
        Char c       -> Char c <> indent nestLevel ds
        Text s       -> Text s <> indent nestLevel ds
        Line         -> padLine nestLevel <> indent nestLevel ds
        a `Concat` b -> indent nestLevel (a:b:ds)
        a `Union` b  -> indent nestLevel (a:ds) `Union` indent nestLevel (b:ds)
    padLine nl = Line <> Text (replicate (nl * indentation) ' ')
```

There are most likely boundary cases, and subtle interactions with the `pretty` function from the book that could mean that this isn't a complete solution, but at this point, I've already used too many hours on this, and I don't feel that I'm *learning Haskell* from struggling with unclear requirements.

Here's a sample GHCI interaction that demonstrates how it works:

```
*PrettyJSON> let value = renderJValue (JObject [("foo", (JObject [("baz", JNumber 123)])), ("bar", JNumber 456)])

*PrettyJSON> putStrLn (pretty 10 (Prettify.nest 4 value))

{
    "foo":
    {
        "baz": 123.0

    },
    "bar": 456.0

}
```

As you can tell, there are too many line breaks, but the basic indentation seems to produce *some* sort of decent-looking nesting.